# Update Query to get rid of "AM" & "PM" in string

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a basic update query:

```
Update WA SET WA.Time_Updated = Replace(Time_Updated, 'PM', '  ');
```

to which I don't get any real error message other than

> Microsoft can't update 251 records etc due to type conversion error

There are 5000 records in there. I have the date column as Date/Time and all my other columns (non-dates) as Short Text. The query just does not update anything in the table and keeps it previously was. Any ideas?

Comment: If `Time_Updated` is of type DATE then you cannot use `Replace` against it.  `Replace` only operates on strings.

Comment: What can I use in that case? I also tried, this which did not work: Update WA SET WA.Time_Updated = MID(WA.Time_Updated,1,5)

Comment: You cannot use any string manipulation functions.  The value is not stored as anything that looks like a string, instead it's a numerical value representing the offset from a particular point in time.  Are you trying to change the actual value (that is, make an afternoon time into the corresponding morning time)?  Or are you simply trying to change how the output is formatted?

Comment: Change the column's Format property to something like "HH:mm", but that won't change the actual value... just the displayed representation of the value.

Comment: basically right now the records are showing up as 12:03:00 PM, 05:15:00 AM etc... what I want to do with this column/field (as a first step anyways) is aggregate all the times so add the 12 hours + 5 hours etc then divide by the sum of another integer (non-date) column

Comment: You are confusing the displayed value with the actual value (which is just a long number). You cannot manipulate date fields like that. If you want the hour component as an integer to do math with just use `HOUR(WA.Time_Updated)`. Stop thinking of the date field as text or anything you can textually or numerically manipulate. Only Date/Time functions will work on it.

Comment: Date/time field is for clock time, not elapsed time. The value is saved as clock time, not as elapsed length of time. Elapsed time should be saved in a number type field, not date/time. So 12 hours 3 minutes would be a decimal: 12.05. What you have now would have to be parsed and calculated to decimal hour value. https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=147496

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I appreciate it. So if this is coming from an excel file that I imported, should I somehow format the date in there first before importing it? If so, how? I chose the hh:mm:ss format there before importing, are you saying I should do something different? June7, I just tried changing to "Number" as the type and it gave me a bunch of gibberish...

Answer (score 0):

Can deal with the imported structure.

Consider:

`Hour("12:03:00 PM") + Minute("12:03:00 PM")/60 + Second("12:03:00 PM")/3600`

This calculates to 12.05

So don't change the raw data, calculate in query. Just use your field name in place of the static value in the expression.

Comment: So how do I do an operation on it (in this case) division, it gives me a different data types error message?

Comment: Don't understand. Are you saying the suggested expression to convert to decimal hours fails? It works for me. Are you still trying to run UPDATE? Don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your text times to *Date* values:

```
Select *, TimeValue([Time_Updated]) As TimeUpdated From WA
```

Then, when you display *TimeUpdate*, format the value as you like.